# uninitialized constant Object::Element in Opal RB

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb

Trying my hand at Opal/JQuery.  My app.rb file looks like this:

```
require 'opal'
require 'opal-jquery'

class HTMLObject
  def initialize

  end

  def write_to_body

  end
end


class HTMLParagraph < HTMLObject
  attr_accessor :inner_html
  def initialize(text)
    @inner_html= text
  end

  def write_to_body

    @body = Element.find("#body")
    @body.append(Element("<p>#{@inner_html}"))
  end
end

p = HTMLParagraph.new("hello world")
p.write_to_body
```

I compile it using the example from the site to app.js. I run it in my web browser with index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="opal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="opal-jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="opal-parser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page I do not see anything. The console reveals this error trace:

```
Uncaught NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Element opal.js:1531
def.$backtrace.backtrace opal.js:1531
def.$raise opal.js:1279
def.$const_missing opal.js:575
Opal.cm opal.js:255
def.$write_to_body app.js:44
(anonymous function) app.js:51
(anonymous function)
```

The JS output file reads thus:

```
 function(__opal) {
  var p = nil, _a, _b, self = __opal.top, __scope = __opal, nil = __opal.nil, $mm = __opal.mm, __breaker = __opal.breaker, __slice = __opal.slice, __klass = __opal.klass;
  (function(__base, __super){
    function HTMLObject() {};
    HTMLObject = __klass(__base, __super, "HTMLObject", HTMLObject);

    var def = HTMLObject.prototype, __scope = HTMLObject._scope;

    def.$initialize = function() {

      return nil;
    };

    def.$write_to_body = function() {

      return nil;
    };

    return nil;
  })(self, null);
  (function(__base, __super){
    function HTMLParagraph() {};
    HTMLParagraph = __klass(__base, __super, "HTMLParagraph", HTMLParagraph);

    var def = HTMLParagraph.prototype, __scope = HTMLParagraph._scope;
    def.inner_html = def.body = nil;

    def.$inner_html = function() {

      return this.inner_html
    }, 
    def['$inner_html='] = function(val) {

      return this.inner_html = val
    }, nil;

    def.$initialize = function(text) {

      return this.inner_html = text;
    };

    def.$write_to_body = function() {
      var _a, _b, _c;
      this.body = ((_a = ((_b = __scope.Element) == null ? __opal.cm("Element") : _b)).$find || $mm('find')).call(_a, "#body");
      return ((_b = this.body).$append || $mm('append')).call(_b, ((_c = this).$Element || $mm('Element')).call(_c, "<p>" + (this.inner_html)));
    };

    return nil;
  })(self, ((_a = __scope.HTMLObject) == null ? __opal.cm("HTMLObject") : _a));
  p = ((_a = ((_b = __scope.HTMLParagraph) == null ? __opal.cm("HTMLParagraph") : _b)).$new || $mm('new')).call(_a, "hello world");
  return ((_b = p).$write_to_body || $mm('write_to_body')).call(_b);
})(Opal);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `opal` and `opal-jquery` directly inside your html, and leaving the requires out of `app.rb`, you can grab them from http://cdnjs.com.

Otherwise I'd like to see the compiled `app.js` (you can put it in a [gist](https://gist.github.com)).

Comment: when I search opal-jquery on cdnjs.com it returns no results. When I search opal it returns opal.js and opal-parser.js

Comment: Would you upload opal-jquery.js to the CDN?

Comment: Sure, I'll do a PR, note that it will take some time to be merged, I'll add a link with the source as soon as it's ready

Comment: And here's the raw contents (please do not hotlink):

https://raw.github.com/opal/cdnjs/177b05aa9ba1fd5247ffaac9485cf38854267a9a/ajax/libs/opal-jquery/0.0.8/opal-jquery.min.js

Comment: I removed the requires from app.rb, included opal-jquery in the html. Here is the js output https://gist.github.com/RedMage/5682298   Now, in addition to the previous error, it says, Uncaught "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". Must I include the original jquery in the HTML file?

Comment: I just tried including jquery in the HTML file. The two prior errors mentioned went away. However, now it says "Uncaught NoMethodError: undefined method `Element' for #<HTMLParagraph:1>"

Answer (score 2):

Originally, I thought this might be because you didn't require the `opal-jquery` gem (I'm assuming you have it installed). Another guess: maybe you need a `<script src="opal-jquery.js"></script>` in your HTML file?

Comment: I originally had it required in my compiler file. I moved the "require 'opal-jquery'" line to app.rb after "require 'opal'" and it still threw the same console error after 'recompiling' and reloading index.html

Comment: I do have the opal-jquery gem installed.

Comment: I'll be sure to try that. I will have to grab the opal-jquery file. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: I could not find any opal-jquery file in the libraries' github. I think I must hunt down the creator and pokes him about this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://github.com/opal/opal-jquery/issues/26#issuecomment-25285375

I had exactly the same issues and got them sorted thanks to opal authors/mantainers.